# How to write a shscript to kill -9 a pid which is found via lsof -i

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm using tomcat, and sometimes when I tell it to stop it doesn't properly kill the process.

My way around this is too do:

```
lsof -i tcp:8080
```

which outputs:

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    888 root   35u  IPv6 780659      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
java    888 root   39r  IPv6 790103      0t0  TCP localhost:58916->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    888 root   40r  IPv6 792585      0t0  TCP localhost:58936->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    888 root   75r  IPv6 785553      0t0  TCP localhost:58701->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    888 root   77r  IPv6 787642      0t0  TCP localhost:58814->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    888 root  130u  IPv6 783894      0t0  TCP localhost:58686->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    888 root  353u  IPv6 780929      0t0  TCP localhost:58632->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

I then run

```
kill -9 pid
```

I want a way to get all the pid numbers and kill them.  Thing is I don't know how to isolate that field.

Comment: If you're sure you only have one `tomcat` process open, you can use `killall -9 tomcat`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is a `-t` (terse) option in `lsof`, which seems to do exactly what you are looking for i.e.

```
$ sudo lsof -ti tcp:80
1387
4538
4539
```

See `man lsof`

```
-t       specifies  that  lsof should produce terse output with process
         identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output  may
         be piped to kill(1).  -t selects the -w option.
```

Assuming you have the necessary permissions, you can pass the result to `kill` as a list of PIDs with command substitution:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti tcp:80)
```

Comment: You've now answered both of the questions I've asked btw ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Do not forget the `--no-run-if-empty` option of **kill** :)

```
lsof -ti :8080 | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill -9
```

That way **kill** will only be run there is a process listening, not need to do the check yourself.

Comment: '--no-run-if-empty' is not supported in BSD(mac)

Comment: `--no-run-if-empty` worked for me on Mac, but I needed to call `lsof -i` rather than `-ti`.

Answer (score 1):

`lsof -i tcp:8080` produces the output, then `| egrep -v "COMMAND PID USER"` drops the header line, then `| awk '{print $2}'` prints the 2nd field, `| sort -n` prepares the numbers for `| uniq`, which only outputs each unique PID once. Putting it all together gives:

```
 lsof -i tcp:8080 | egrep -v "COMMAND PID USER" | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq
```

But, `pkill -KILL tomcat` or `killall -KILL tomcat` is easier.

Comment: Tomcat process is not named "tomcat" that's the problem. It is just a normal java process, extra work has to be done to identify the correct process if there are other java processes running at the same time.

Comment: @TerryWang Yup, that's the problem I had as well.  Steeldrivers answer is working great.

Answer (score 0):

The one liner from @waltinator is great.

I'll add some more flavor to it:

```sh
lsof -i tcp:8080 | egrep -v "COMMAND PID USER" | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq | xargs kill -9
```

OR

```sh
kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:8080 | egrep -v "COMMAND PID USER" | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq)
```

> NOTE: this is still very basic, you may need to add more salt and pepper to make it more robust in a real environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I came up with a little bit of error checking.

```
#!/bin/bash

PORT=$1

if ! [[ "$PORT" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ;
then
  printf "error: '$PORT' is not a number.\n\nUsage killport <port number>\n"
  exit 1
fi

PID=$(lsof -ti:$PORT)

if ! [[ "$PID" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ;
then
  printf "no proccess found, nothing to kill.\n"
  exit 0
fi

printf "killing process $PID running on $PORT\n"
kill -9 $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple fish shell function

```
function kill-port
  set pids (lsof -ti tcp:$argv)
  if test $pids
    kill -9 $pids
  else
    echo "No proccesses on that port to kill to see for your self -- lsof -i tcp:$argv"
  end
end
```

just stick this sucker in a file at this location `~/.config/fish/functions/kill-port.fish` and your good to go. 
You can call it like `kill-port 8000`